# CMake add system-wide prefix path

Tags: cmake

I want every CMake project that uses `boost` (or any other lib) to find it in custom directory, for example `/home/someuser/mylibs` or `C:/mylibs`.

To achieve this I may add in `CMakeLists.txt` following command:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/someuser/mylibs")
```

This is not very comfortable when I cooperate with different people on different projects. The question is: can I use some environment variable to set it or there's another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to add `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/boost/` when calling CMake to configure your project. But, of course, you can also set an environment variable, e.g. `BOOST_DIR` and then read it out using CMake:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{BOOST_DIR})
```